# How to change width of track for horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, scrollbar, android-scrollbar

I have got a horizontal recyclerView which use horizontal custom scrollbars but i have an issue, thumb is over than the track, how can i specify the width of track for scrollbar?

here is my RecyclerView:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/itemRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    app:layoutManager=".LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/skinName2"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_horizontal_thumb"
    android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_horizontal_track"
    tools:itemCount="15"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_item" />
```

Here is my custom thumb:

````
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:height="1dp">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>```
    
    and here is my track
    ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:height="1dp">
            <shape
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
````

issue is here

[image]

Any ideas?